# Cnosdb data node panic after restart data node

Tags: database, cnosdb

Cnosdb data node panic after restart data node.
Env:

```
version: 52cd675
1m2d
load data 200g;
```

To Reproduce:
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
select count(1) from readings;
kill -9 data node processes pid;
nohup ./target/release/cnosdb run -c 64 -m 256 --config ./config/config_31001.toml > /data/cnosdb/logs/data_node.1001.log &
```

Expected behavior
Cnosdb restart normally,no errors!

Additional context

```
    2023-03-14T05:48:20.980084Z  WARN tskv::wal: recovering version set from seq '362108'
    at tskv/src/wal.rs:380

The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: MemoryExhausted
Location: /home/bca/code/cnosdb/tskv/src/wal.rs:435

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 9 frames hidden ⋮
```